# how to submit text to convert url or link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am submitting a text like php.net but cannot replace the link but when I will post www.php.net in this time replace auto-link.

Question - 1
my question is when I will post just a php.net it also replaces the link.

Question - 2
And another question is how to show iframe in a favicon icon with his webpage link?

see my code I will replace in this system

```
$find = array('`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+[[:alnum:]]/?)`si', '`((?<!//)(www\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si');

$replace = array('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', '<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

$body = preg_replace($find,$replace,$body);
```